# What is the difference between the args 'index' and 'values' for the pandas interpolate function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the difference between the pandas DataFrame interpolate function called with args 'index' and 'values' respectively? It's ambiguous from the documentation:

> pandas.DataFrame.interpolate
>
> method : str, default ‘linear’
>
> Interpolation technique to use. One of:
>
> ‘linear’: Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced. This is the only method supported on MultiIndexes.
>
> ‘time’: Works on daily and higher resolution data to interpolate given length of interval.
>
> ‘index’, ‘values’: use the actual numerical values of the index."

Both appear to use the numerical values of the index, is this the case?

UPDATE:

Following ansev's answer, they do indeed do the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's pretty clear, imagine you're going to interpolate points. The values ​​of your DataFrame represent the **Y values**, it is about filling in the missing values ​​in **Y** with **some logic**, for them an interpolation function is used, in this case for the variable **X** there are two options, to assume a **fixed step**, **independent of the index** or take into account the values ​​of the **index**.

**Example with linear interpolation:**

Here for each row the index increases by 1 upward and therefore there is no difference between the methods.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Y':[1,np.nan,3]})
print(df)
     Y
0  1.0
1  NaN
2  3.0

print(df.interpolate(method = 'index'))
     Y
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0

print(df.interpolate())
     Y
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
```

---

**but if we change the index values...**

```
df.index = [0,1,10000]



print(df.interpolate(method = 'index'))



            Y
0      1.0000
1      1.0002  #(3-1)*((1-0)/(10000-0))
10000  3.0000

print(df.interpolate())
         Y
0      1.0
1      2.0
10000  3.0

df.index = [0,0.1,1]
print(df.interpolate(method = 'index'))
       Y
0.0  1.0
0.1  1.2  #(3-1)*((0.1-0)/(1-0))
1.0  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks, my question was specifically whether there was any difference between using "method='index'" vs "method='values'". it looks like there is no difference on the test df I am using, but I was wondering if there was one

Comment: I omitted this, but it is clear that if the documentation indicates both, it must be the same